# Flutter Firebase Phone Auth: Separate Code logic from UI

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to make an app where I authenticate using my phone number via Firebase. I currently integrated the Logic Into the UI to see if everything works and it does perfectly. Now, I want to separate the logic into another file. The problem is that I don't know how to notify the UI page when the message has been sent so it moves to the code verification part. What is the best practice to communicate between the Logic part and the UI. I have seen some people using the Get library. Should I look into that?

Here is the problem:

Once I press on the button I call the function:

```
await AuthService().registerUser( _phone_number_controller.text, context);
```

And on the other side a Future function

```
Future verifyUserPhoneNumber(String mobile, BuildContext context) {
    auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: mobile,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {...},
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {...},
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {...},
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {...},
    );
}
```

How can I make the function notify the UI page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider any state management library. I would suggest `bloc` to start. You can refer authentication example from the following [repo](https://github.com/felangel/bloc)